# Zero divisor graph of commutative ring

Tags: graph-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $Zd(R)=P_1∪P_2$, where $P_1$ and $P_2$ are maximal (prime) ideals in $Zd(R)$. Let $P_1∩P_2≠{0}$. Show that the diameter of the zero divisor graph $Γ(R)$ equals $3$. (Note that diam$(Γ(R))≤3$.)

Comment: I'm going to post my aswer, but I think there is some thing messing on it!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a∈P_1\setminus P_2$ and $b∈P_2\setminus P_1$. Then $ab∈P_1∩P_2≠\{0\}$.
If $ab=0$, then $d(a,b)=1$. So, assume that $ab≠0$. It is clear that $a+b ∉P_1∪P_2=Zd(R)$. Thus ann$((a,b) )=\{0\}$. Thus $d(a,b)≥3$ in $Γ(R)$. But diam$(Γ(R))≤3$. Hence $d(a,b)=3$ and so diam$(Γ(R) )=3$.